# How to relate User and Client Portfolio models in Active Record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm writing rails client phone-book for a company that provides audit services. The company has a client portfolio and all these clients are divided among all the employees (managers, seniors and assistants). See the following diagram, for instance:

```
                               Manager
                            40 customers
                                  |
                   ________________________________
                   |                              |
                Senior                          Senior
             20 customers                    20 customers
                   |                              |
           __________________             _________________
           |                |             |               |
      Assistant        Assistant      Assistant        Assistant
    10 customers     10 customers    10 customers     10 customers


               *Total customer portfolio: 40 customers
```

The application will show to the user a list of phone numbers belonging to the client the user has assigned, for which I need to associate the User model with the Client model, the question is: which one of all the Active Record associations provides the best solution for this problem?

After reading the [association basics](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) described in Ruby on Rails Guides, I think I could use the `has_many :through` with a third model (Assignment), given that every client in the portfolio needs to have a manager, a senior and an assistant assigned to it (as it happens away from the keyboard).

My solution is the following:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assignments
  has_many :clients, through: :assignments
end

class Assignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :client    
end

class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assignments
  has_many :users, through: :assignments
end
```

What do you think of the solution above? or which one would be a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a table called Relationship (or something) with two foreign_ids concerning what you want the User and client to be able to do with one another (example to be able to "Follow" one another => Follower_id and Following_id). Define methods in your Models related to those ids and then call those methods in your views to display the relationship.

Comment: Thank you, that's actually really useful :)